# change default cursor icon UITextView iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I need to change default cursor icon of `UITextView`. I want to change it as a circle icon instead of a line as shown below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to change textView's original caret.

You should make your custom one. To do so  make a subclass of UITextView:

```
@interface CustomTextView()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *caretImageView;

@end

@implementation CustomTextView

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(textDidChange:)
                                                 name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification
                                               object:self];

    self.caretImageView = // create and customize your caret view
    //...

    [self addSubview:self.caretImageView];

    // Make careImageView to blink every 0.5 secs
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(blink)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}

- (void)blink
{
    self.caretImageView.alpha = !(BOOL)self.caretImageView.alpha;
}

// Hiding original caret
- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position
{
    return CGRectZero;
}

// Repositioning caretImageView everytime when text did change
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
    CGPoint endPoint = // calculate the x and y coords of the text's end.

    CGRect frame = self.caretImageView.frame;
    frame.origin = endPoint;
    self.caretImageView.frame = frame;
}


//
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's possible. I don't think Apple exposes the code that draws the cursor in text views.